# two dimension array; one dimension length is defined one is undefined in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to make an array which one dimension's length is defined but the other one is undefined
I try to do it with "LIST" and I dont know how to make a two dimension array which I already know how much is the length of one dimension

Comment: Sounds like you need an array of lists.

Comment: yeah i need an array of list

Comment: Search for `jagged array`.

Comment: How are you going to access it ? what will it contain?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make an array of lists. But make sure you include System.Collections.Generic in your class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

in the body of the method or class where you need this:

```
var arrayOfList = new List<int>[10];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // initialize each entry of the array
    arrayOfList[i] = new List<int>();
}

// add some stuff to entry one at a time
arrayOfList[0].Add(1);
// add some integers as a range
arrayOfList[0].AddRange(new [] {2, 3, 4});

// add some stuff to entry 1
arrayOfList[1].AddRange(new [] {5, 6});
```

If you don't want to use the generic list class, you can do a jagged array but it isn't as nice to deal with.

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[3][];

// initialize before using or else you'll get an error
jaggedArray[0] = new int[5];
jaggedArray[1] = new int[4];
jaggedArray[2] = new int[2];

// populate them like this:
jaggedArray[0] = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
jaggedArray[1] = new int[] { 0, 2, 4, 6 }; 
jaggedArray[2] = new int[] { 11, 22 };
```

See more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Comment: Try again with the code above, I think perhaps you aren't including the `Systems.Collections.Generic` library?